# Create Pivot table in SQL without Pivot Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

All,

I have the following table.

```
SalesDate   SubChannel      Country  NetQuantity
20140826    TV Attributable      CA          194
20140826    Unknown              CA           60
20140826    Web Property         CA           64
20140826    Overall              CA          264
20140826    Search               CA           70
```

I want to display this information as a pivot table.

Before I was using the following piece of code to make this happen, but the current system I have to migrate to, doesn't support pivot functions.

```
Select      SalesDate,
    Country,
    [Search],
    [Unknown],
    [Web Property],
    [TV Attributable],
    [Overall]
From temp
PIVOT
(
Sum([NetQuantity])
FOR [SubChannel] IN ([Search],[Unknown],[Web Property],[TV Attributable],[Overall])
) as p
```

Can somebody help me accomplish the following output:

```
SalesDate   Country Search  Unknown  WebProperty       TVAttributable      Overall
20140826         CA     70       60           64                  194          264
```

Comment: What system are you using? There might be some silimar function if pivot isn't supported.

Comment: I search all the documentation and even when the system uses psql, it doesn't support pivot functions. So I am just trying to find a work around. But so far I haven't been able to come up with a query that could do the trick.

Comment: You tagged the post with psql, is it Postgresql you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statements with a `GROUP BY` to do the pivot "manually";

```
SELECT "SalesDate", MAX("Country") "Country",
  MAX(CASE WHEN "SubChannel"='Search' 
           THEN "NetQuantity" END) "Search",
  MAX(CASE WHEN "SubChannel"='Unknown' 
           THEN "NetQuantity" END) "Unknown",
  MAX(CASE WHEN "SubChannel"='Web Property' 
           THEN "NetQuantity" END) "WebProperty",
  MAX(CASE WHEN "SubChannel"='TV Attributable' 
           THEN "NetQuantity" END) "TVAttributable",
  MAX(CASE WHEN "SubChannel"='Overall' 
           THEN "NetQuantity" END) "Overall"
FROM temp
GROUP BY "SalesDate";
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cb0bf/8).

Basically, the `CASE` statements pick out a value if the subchannel matches or null if no match. The `MAX` is then used to pick the greatest (non null) match for each subchannel.

If the sales dates need to be split by country, you can just replace the `MAX("Country")` expression with just "Country" and add Country to the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE to determine what to sum up for every category. As you use SUM in the example pivot, I think you might want this and not MAX:

```
Select
    "SalesDate",
    "Country",
    sum(case when "SubChannel" = 'Search' then "NetQuantity" else 0 end) "Search",
    sum(case when "SubChannel" = 'Unknown' then "NetQuantity" else 0 end) "Unknown",
    sum(case when "SubChannel" = 'Web Property' then "NetQuantity" else 0 end) "Web Property",
    sum(case when "SubChannel" = 'TV Attributable' then "NetQuantity" else 0 end) "TV Attributable",
    sum(case when "SubChannel" = 'Overall' then "NetQuantity" else 0 end) "Overall"
from temp
group by "SalesDate", "Country"
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b6b04/1)

Comment: @Pierre I thought so.