# Is it possible to create columns from rows in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table

Let's say I have a query that returns the following:

| Country |
| --- |
| US |
| FR |
| UK |
| IT |

Is it possible to use the result of that query to create a new query with columns as country names like the following:

| US | FR | UK | IT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

My main goal is to create a new query dynamically in case the number of countries increases in the first query.

I am trying to avoid using postgresql extension tablefunc as it needs to be installed. The production db does not have the crosstab extension installed, so I am trying to avoid it. Thanks!

Comment: [Crosstab questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)

Comment: I don't want to install an extension to the prod db unless it is not possible to accomplish this task without crosstab extension.

Comment: You don't need the crosstab extensions. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58062286) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67549662) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938927/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52392501/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65965872/)